# Making a background shadow with PNG or CSS?

Tags: css, background

Can someone take a look at my background shadow?  Here is the link:
[link text](http://www.logicpkg.com/home.htm)

I'm trying to find the best solution for having a background shadow for a card in the front (layered).

Is it possible to make the sides of shadow cave in with CSS?

I'm currently using a PNG with transparency and I can't get the shadow to match with the background!

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: what browsers are you targeting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get your image to line up you can do it in css:

```
#card_main {
  background:url("/img/shadow.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
  margin:0 auto;
  min-height:800px;
  position:relative;
  top:-1px;
  width:980px;
}
```

Though your background gray color seems to be different in the image than the background.

Comment: I added the transparent to the css of the image, but I still see an edge.  The background and the shadow were both saved as PNG's..  Am I missing something?

Comment: Yeah, the position: relative and top: -1px.

Answer (score 0):

you can also make your shadow.png only be the text shadow, not including the background-color for the header and content area in the png.

or, you can simply use the `box-shadow` css declaration for webkit and FF. and a filter for IE.  if you're interested in this solution i can post some sample code.